# What are all the bow types?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm curious as to what all the bow types are, and their order of power.

From what I can gather so far:

- Long bow
- Hunters bow
- Orc bow
- Dwarven bow
- Forsworn Bow
- Elven Bow
- Glass Bow
- Ebony bow

I assume a Daedric bow as well, but have yet to see one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a list of all the bows, excluding all the enchantment possibilities. 
Minor spoilers, obviously.

```
Name              Weight Value Damage
-------------------------------------
Ancient Nord Bow  12     45    8 
Angi's Bow        7      50    7 
Daedric Bow       18     2500  19 
Dravin's Bow      7      50    7 
Dwarven Bow       10     270   12 
Ebony Bow         16     1440  17 
Elven Bow         12     470   13 
Falmer Bow        15     135   12 
Falmer Supple Bow 20     410   15 
Forsworn Bow      11     145   12 
Gauldur Blackbow  12     5     4 
Glass Bow         14     820   15 
Hunting Bow       7      50    7 
Hunting Bow       4      5     0 
Imperial Bow      8      90    9 
Karliah's Bow     9      5     25 
Long Bow          5      30    6 
Nord Hero Bow     7      200   11 
Orcish Bow        9      150   10 
Supple Ancient 
      Nord Bow    18     235   14
```

Source: [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bow#Bows)

Comment: Thanks, looks great. Really need to unblock UESP here at work. Pretty sure it is work related. ;)

Comment: It should be noted that Karliah's Bow / Nightengale Bow is leveled, as is the Gauldur Blackbow.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a list of all the bows in Skyrim:

###### Notes:

"**Time**" means the full draw time of the bow in seconds
"**QS**" is the "Quick Shot" perk, which allows you to draw a bow 30% faster 
**"Best Base DPS"** is the DPS of the bow when used with Dragonbone Arrows and the Quick Shot perk
The base damage and DPS does not include any damage added from the enchantments that exist on some of the unique bows listed.

| Name | Base Damage | Weight | Speed | Time | DPS | QS Time | QS DPS | Best Base DPS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Ancient Nord Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ancient_Nord_Bow) (includes [Gauldur Blackbow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Gauldur_Blackbow) levels 1-18) | 8 | 12 | 0.875 | 2.90 | 2.76 | 2.46 | 3.25 | 13.42 |
| [Auriel's Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Auriel%27s_Bow) [[DG]](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dawnguard) | 13 | 11 | 1 | 2.66 | 4.89 | 2.28 | 5.71 | 16.69 |
| [Bound Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bound_Weapon) | 18 | 0 | 0.875 | 2.90 | 6.21 | 2.46 | 7.32 | 17.48 |
| [Bound Bow (Mystic)](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bound_Weapon) | 24 | 0 | 0.875 | 2.90 | 8.28 | 2.46 | 9.76 | 19.92 |
| [Bow of Shadows](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bow_of_Shadows_(item)) [[CC]](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bow_of_Shadows) | 19 | 18 | 0.9375 | 2.77 | 6.86 | 2.36 | 8.04 | 18.63 |
| [Bow of the Hunt](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bow_of_the_Hunt) | 10 | 7 | 0.937 | 2.77 | 3.61 | 2.36 | 4.23 | 14.81 |
| [Daedric Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Daedric_Bow) | 19 | 18 | 0.5 | 4.32 | 4.40 | 3.55 | 5.35 | 12.38 |
| [Dragonbone Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragonbone_Bow) | 20 | 20 | 0.75 | 3.21 | 6.22 | 2.70 | 7.40 | 16.65 |
| [Drainspell Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Drainspell_Bow) | 14 | 6 | 0.875 | 2.90 | 4.83 | 2.46 | 5.70 | 15.86 |
| [Dwarven Black Bow of Fate](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dwarven_Black_Bow_of_Fate) [[DB]](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragonborn) | 13 | 10 | 0.75 | 3.21 | 4.05 | 2.70 | 4.81 | 14.06 |
| [Dwarven Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dwarven_Bow) | 12 | 10 | 0.75 | 3.21 | 3.73 | 2.70 | 4.44 | 13.69 |
| [Ebony Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ebony_Bow) | 17 | 16 | 0.5625 | 3.95 | 4.30 | 3.27 | 5.20 | 12.84 |
| [Elven Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Elven_Bow) (includes [Firiniel's End](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Firiniel%27s_End)) | 13 | 12 | 0.6875 | 3.42 | 3.81 | 2.86 | 4.55 | 13.30 |
| [Falmer Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Falmer_Bow) | 12 | 15 | 0.75 | 3.21 | 3.73 | 2.70 | 4.44 | 13.69 |
| [Falmer Supple Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Falmer_Supple_Bow) | 15 | 20 | 0.75 | 3.21 | 4.67 | 2.70 | 5.55 | 14.80 |
| [Forsworn Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Forsworn_Bow) | 12 | 11 | 0.875 | 2.90 | 4.14 | 2.46 | 4.88 | 15.04 |
| [Glass Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Glass_Bow) | 15 | 14 | 0.625 | 3.66 | 4.10 | 3.04 | 4.93 | 13.11 |
| [Glass Bow of the Stag Prince](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Glass_Bow_of_the_Stag_Prince) [[DB]](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragonborn) | 16 | 14 | 0.625 | 3.66 | 4.38 | 3.04 | 5.26 | 13.47 |
| [Hunting Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hunting_Bow) (includes [Angi's Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Angi%27s_Bow) and [Dravin's Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dravin%27s_Bow)) | 7 | 7 | 0.937 | 2.77 | 2.53 | 2.36 | 2.96 | 13.54 |
| [Imperial Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Imperial_Bow) | 9 | 8 | 0.75 | 3.21 | 2.80 | 2.70 | 3.33 | 12.58 |
| [Karliah's Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Karliah%27s_Bow) | 25 | 9 | 0.625 | 3.66 | 6.88 | 3.04 | 8.22 | 16.43 |
| [Long Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Long_Bow) (includes [Froki's Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Froki%27s_Bow)) | 6 | 5 | 1 | 2.66 | 2.26 | 2.28 | 2.64 | 13.61 |
| [Nightingale Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nightingale_Bow) levels 1-18 | 12 | 9 | 0.5 | 4.32 | 2.78 | 3.55 | 3.38 | 10.41 |
| [Nightingale Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nightingale_Bow) levels 19-26 | 13 | 11 | 0.5 | 4.32 | 3.01 | 3.55 | 3.69 | 10.69 |
| [Nightingale Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nightingale_Bow) levels 27-35 | 15 | 13 | 0.5 | 4.32 | 3.47 | 3.55 | 4.22 | 11.26 |
| [Nightingale Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nightingale_Bow) levels 36-45 | 17 | 15 | 0.5 | 4.32 | 3.94 | 3.55 | 4.78 | 11.82 |
| [Nightingale Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nightingale_Bow) levels 46+ | 19 | 18 | 0.5 | 4.32 | 4.40 | 3.55 | 5.35 | 12.38 |
| [Nord Hero Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nord_Hero_Bow) | 11 | 7 | 0.875 | 2.90 | 3.80 | 2.46 | 4.47 | 14.64 |
| [Nordic Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nordic_Bow) [[DB]](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragonborn) | 13 | 11 | 0.6875 | 3.42 | 3.81 | 2.86 | 4.55 | 13.30 |
| [Orcish Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Orcish_Bow) | 10 | 9 | 0.812 | 3.04 | 3.29 | 2.57 | 3.89 | 13.61 |
| [Ruin's Edge](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ruin%27s_Edge_(item)) [[CC]](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ruin%27s_Edge) | 12 | 7 | 0.875 | 2.90 | 4.14 | 2.46 | 4.88 | 15.04 |
| [Stalhrim Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Stalhrim_Bow) [[DB]](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragonborn) | 17 | 15 | 0.5625 | 3.95 | 4.30 | 3.27 | 5.20 | 12.84 |
| [Supple Ancient Nord Bow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Supple_Ancient_Nord_Bow) (includes [Gauldur Blackbow](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Gauldur_Blackbow) levels 19+) | 14 | 18 | 0.875 | 2.90 | 4.83 | 2.46 | 5.70 | 15.86 |
| [Zephyr](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Zephyr) [[DG]](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dawnguard) | 12 | 10 | 1 | 2.66 | 4.51 | 2.28 | 5.27 | 16.25 |

<sup>Source: [UESP Wiki, "Skyrim - Archery" article](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Archery#Detailed_Bow_Comparison)</sup>

The [Dawnguard DLC](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dawnguard) adds crossbows, which are also under the Archery skill tree:

| Name | Weight | Value | Damage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Crossbow | 14 | 120 | 19 |
| Enhanced Crossbow | 15 | 200 | 19 |
| Dwarven Crossbow | 20 | 350 | 22 |
| Enhanced Dwarven Crossbow | 21 | 550 | 22 |

<sup>Source: [UESP Wiki, "Skyrim - Crossbows" article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Crossbow#Crossbows)</sup>